# Change text to pseudo-random color using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change the text color using the following code, but I get an error: `Uncaught syntax: unexpected string` when `.each` is called. I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
function random_rgb() {
  colors = ['8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  r = colors.eq(Math.floor(Math.random * 8));
  g = colors.eq(Math.floor(Math.random * 8));
  b = colors.eq(Math.floor(Math.random * 8));
  return '#' + r + g + b;
};

$(document).ready({

  $("span.number").each(function(){
    this.style.color = random_rgb();
  });

});
```

UPDATE

I've created a jsfiddle (forgive me I'm not great w/ this app) https://jsfiddle.net/yrnqr566/

The color turns up black every time.

Comment: What's your HTML like? Got a fiddle to show off this error?

Comment: See update please.

Comment: `Math.random` is a function, you need to use parenthesis to call it : `Math.random()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of errors, see this fiddle for the fixes;
https://jsfiddle.net/yrnqr566/10/

`$(function() {...});` is a better alternative to document.ready...

Also, you need to use `Math.random()` with open/close brackets, as this is a function not a property.

Third, you were using `.eq()` on an array. `[]` is the correct syntax.

```
function random_rgb() {
  colors = ['8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  r = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
  g = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
  b = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
  return '#' + r + g + b;
};

$(function() {
  $('span.number').each(function() {
    this.style.color = random_rgb();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Guess you need something like this, you had a few errors in your `random_rgb() function`.

 Also `jquery` way would be `$(this).css('color',random_rgb());`

```js
function random_rgb() {
  colors = ['8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  r = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
  g = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
  b = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
  return '#' + r + g + b;
}

$("span.number").each(function() {
  this.style.color = random_rgb();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="number">Some Long Text</span>
<span class="number">Some Long Text</span>
<span class="number">Some Long Text</span>
<span class="number">Some Long Text</span>
<span class="number">Some Long Text</span>
<span class="number">Some Long Text</span>
<span class="number">Some Long Text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

shoud return  something like :return rgb(255, 0, 0)
 or try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('div').css('background',randrgb());
})
```

Comment: Sorry, the function says rgb but I want a hex value.